# Appscript doGet not working after using company google account

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-apps-script, cors

I'm running into an issue where calling an Appscript function returns a CORS error, even though it shouldn't.

I have a webapp hosted through Firebase that makes use of Appscript to fetch data to pages. Originally, my app was set up on my private account byut I've moved it over to my work account. So, in my app, I signed into my app using a company email, for example, ryan@generation.co.za using Google popup firebase SDK.

In my app script, I deployed the doGet function as

Web app
Execute as
`Me (ryan@generation.co.za)`

and chose for Who has access:

`Anyone within Generation`

but when I try to call that function in my app, it returns a CORS error. Could it be that my vue webapp/Appscript does not properly register the login as a company login?
I've tried to send the email used to login to the app as part of the fetch request to Appscript, but this didn't work either.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!